# MySQL to JSON not formed properly

Tags: mysql, json

I am trying to return JSON formatted results from a MySQL query but cannot get the correct format - it needs to be e.g.

```
{comCom:'test 3', comUid:'63',... etc
```

But what I'm getting is without apostrophes

```
{comCom:test 3, comUid:63,... etc
```

I am running the query in PHP as follows (shortened for ease of reading)

```
$result = mysql_query("select...

...GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{comCom:',ww.comment, ', comUid:',h.user_id,', comName:',h.name,', comPic:',h.live_prof_pic,',comUrl:',h.url,',comWhen:',time_ago(ww.dateadded),'}')) comment,...
```

How can I get the punctuation?

I know `mysql_query` is deprecated btw, just in process of moving things to `MySQLi`

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just escape the `'` character with `\'`?

```
...GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{comCom:\'',ww.comment, '\', comUid:\'',h.user_id,'\', comName:\'',h.name,'\', comPic:\'',h.live_prof_pic,'\',comUrl:\'',h.url,'\',comWhen:\'',time_ago(ww.dateadded),'\'}'))
```

or use a mixture of `"` with `'`

```
...GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("{comCom:'",ww.comment, "', comUid:'",h.user_id,"', comName:'",h.name,"', comPic:'",h.live_prof_pic,"',comUrl:'",h.url,"',comWhen:'",time_ago(ww.dateadded),"'}"))
```

Comment: Tried those but breaks it for some reason, probably due to $result = mysql_query("select...

Comment: Do they show the correct JSON layout if they are executed on the server?